# ng-click function not recognzing changes inside table data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

i created a table with one editable column. i want users to be able to save changes in this column cells, but though the call executes and sends the correct data before the change, it won't recognize changes in the table after data loaded.
this is how i create table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-controller="tableCtrl" 
       ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <thead>
        <td>user name</td>
        <td>script name</td>
        <td>cron format</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(user_id, row) in data | filter:search">
        <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in row ">
            <td ng-model="user_name">{{user(user_id)}}</td>
            <td ng-model="script_name">{{script(script_id)}}</td>
            <td ng-model="cron_format">
                <span contenteditable="true" 
                    ng-repeat="l in letters(cron_format) track by $index"
                >{{l}}</span>
            <button class="save"
              ng-click="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)">save</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the result is this table:
[image]

and cron format is editable. but when i call `saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)`

it sends the values initialized the table.
this is the saveCron function:

```
 $scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat){
    $.post("updateCronChange.php","user_id=userId&script_id=scriptId&cron=cronFormat", function(data){
        //function gets correct params
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userId + scriptId +cronFormat;
    });
}
```

how can i make it send the modified cron_format after end user changed it? thanks..

Comment: You're doing Jquery inside Angular, that's not really recommended. I suggest you use Angular's `$http` provider for AJAX requests, and also do those inside a service, not a controller. Update the relevant `ng-model` when you return, not the DOM element itself.

Comment: Could you please add a plunker or jsfiddle link?